# Chebyshev interval / binomial

Tags: probability-theory

I've seen the Chebyshev Inequality used to show that if you flip a fair coin a million times, with 95% confidence the number of heads will be between 425,000 and 575,000.
It uses the binomial STDEV, since the coin flip is a Bernoulli trial.
So, does that extend to the multinomial distribution, as a generalization of the binomial?

Comment: The chebyshev-inequality often gives poor results, but it is true for EVERY distribution.

Comment: What I'm stuck on is that the Uniform Distribution is flat, and always has the same probability, yet when repeated the sum of events behaves in Binomial fashion, and the distribution narrows to where p and q can be shown to exist in a central 15% window, with 95% certainty. So a 'fair coin toss' is not really 50/50, but 42.5/57.5, even though it is 50/50 for a single, unique event that will never recur.

Comment: As said, the chebyshev-inequality is usually not a good estimate, the real confidence interval is much tighter, to find good bounds you can use the central limit theorem or for the given case (throwing a coin a million times) the normal distribution can be used. You easily get expectation $500\ 000$ and standard deviation $500$ , so with $99.7%$ probability, the number of heads will lie in the interval $[498\ 500,501\ 500]$ , much tighther than the chebychev-inequality predicts (it is only an inequality, not giving a good confidecnce-interval)

Comment: In the long term, the ratio bewtween the number of heads and the number of throws will actually tend to $\frac{1}{2}$. If you have more complicated distributions than the normal distribution, but you have many trials, you can as said, use the central limit theorem, to get good bounds. Again, the chebyshev-inequality only gives a true, but not a good bound. As I interpreted the question , you only want to know whether the chebyshev-inequality can be used in this case. Yes, it can be used, but you do not get good confidence-intervals. Hope, I could clarify the point!

Comment: Forgive the folly, but I have about 10 years of lottery data, because its actual data, based on random natural phenomena. The occurrence of the numbers behaves as Uniform, actually the sum of Gamma Dist's in the columns.  Each SET of numbers has  the same probability by combinatorics, yet the actual sets that come out follow some rules that point at a reduced solution set.  The averages agree, but "point samples", not "sample populations" follow distinct rules.  Robert Laughlin used the term, "Emergence."  More simply, I wouldn't bet "1,2,3,4,5,6", "10,20,30,40,50,60",or "55,56,57,58,59,60".